replicate prod angular build error on local
I am getting errors like

error NG8002: Can't bind to 'svgIcon' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-icon'.

I don't get this on my development machine.  I tried to replicate it by running "npm run build –prod" but it builds fine without any errors.
What do I have to do to replicate build configuration or mode on my local computer?  I am using angular 13.

does the local give any warning in the terminal or browser console?

could also be a case of JIT vs AOT compilation?

Could be an issue related to npm packages versions mismatch. Check that your dev machine has same nodejs and npm version, save the package.json and package-lock.json files you have locally somewhere for later evaluation, delete package-lock.json file and node_modules, run npm install command and try to build the production version of your app. Most likely you have versions in your package.json file specified as "^x.x.x", so your prod server probably installing newest version of those libs and they have their API changed compared to your locally installed libs.

@JamesAshok no it doesn't.  I don't see these errors on my console nor on browser

@SergeySosunov thanks for the suggestion.  I will give it a try and let you know

@JamesAshok What do you mean exactly by JIT vs AOT.  is there a command I can run to try different approach?

@SergeySosunov nope, didn't work

@wil production build uses AOT compilation, while dev build uses JIT compilation. Try enabling/disabling AOT from angular.json and see if issue is replicable. If it is replicable, you may refer https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler for potential fixes.

for anyone who may run into this issue.
You can try ng build --aot or
change the tsconfig.json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"strictInjectionParameters": true,
"strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
"strictTemplates": true
}
to replicate the build for prod
